# Ovirt Hosted Engine live migration

Tags: virtualization, ovirt

I have trouble with live migration HE in ovirt.
I have 2 nodes. 
[My nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igvMQ.png)
if i migrate HE to other node, i getting an error
[My error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbCs4.png)

Ovirt version 4.1

If i run host-deploy on node, i getting an error

> Failed to execute stage 'Environment customization': Setup of additional hosts using this software is not allowed anymore. Please use the engine web interface to deploy any additional hosts.

Comment: Both errors are pretty clear - you need to configure the second host as an HE host via the engine UI/API and everything should work. Are both hosts in the same cluster BTW?

Comment: Yes, Hosts are in same cluster. And I enable "HE deploy".

Comment: Just as a thought, take the second host to maintenance and reboot it, and also restart the ovirt-engine service. If you took all the steps and the system still refuses to work, it might be a bug better reported at users@ovirt.org

Answer (score -1):

sometimes the live migration of the ovirt-hosted-engine failed for me too. Log in via SSH on a server in your cluster and check via `hosted-engine --vm-status` what the score of the server is. Sometimes the activation of the server failed and the state of the node is still in maintenance. 
Best workaround for me was to reboot the server or try in the UI the maintenance mode and actiation again.

Do you have your Power Management set up?